# How to getWindow() in LockScreen?

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-framework

I am modifying `LockScreen.java` in Android source package (4.1.2). Now, I want to `getWindow()` to add some appropriate flags, such as:

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayourParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

but I don't know how to call this function in a non-`Activity` class. I tried:

```
Window window = mContext.getWindow()
```

but it doesn't work.

I wonder if it is possible to use `getWindow()` in `LockScreen.java`?

Comment: use context of Class which Extends Application where u can get & set context.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? I cannot get your idea

Comment: refer this link to solved context problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android

Comment: sorry, but I found that it cannot solve my problem. The main point here is that I am working on the Android's framework, so I cannot use that way. Anyway, thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you try to do. From the explanation of `WindowManager.LayourParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`:

> Window flag: special flag to let windows be shown when the screen is
>   locked. This will let application windows take precedence over key
>   guard or any other lock screens.

So from this definition I understand that you want to make a window of ScreenLock before the window of ScreenLock :)

I guess you want to create a Screen that will be shown before ScreenLock window. If yes, I advise you to create a system application with the activity, where you can set this parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The important point here is that I have to customize the existed lockscreen by modifying LockScreen.java (in Android framework) instead of using system application. This new lockscreen will replace default Android lockscreen in new mobile brand.